# How to select data with multiple row output from 1 row (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I have data on table test like this

```
customer_no | name | chance
---------------------------
00000000001 | AAAA |     3
00000000002 | BBBB |     2
00000000003 | CCCC |     1
```

Now,i want to select from table test with multiple output that calculate by value of field chance

output like this

```
customer_no | name
------------------
00000000001 | AAAA
00000000001 | AAAA
00000000001 | AAAA
00000000002 | BBBB
00000000002 | BBBB
00000000003 | CCCC
```

how to select command in pgsql database?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT  customer_no, name FROM (
  SELECT  test.*, 
          generate_series(1,chance) i
  FROM test
) test;
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9b879/4).

Comment: +1, totally forgot about generate_series in postgres, i'm working with SQL Server all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with recursive CTE_nums as (
    select max(chance) as num from test
    union all
    select num - 1 from CTE_nums
    where num > 1
)
select
   t.customer_no, t.name
from test as t
   inner join CTE_nums as n on n.num <= t.chance
order by 1, 2
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cf267/9)